# Can I register a static method as a Guava EventBus subscriber?

Tags: java, guava

I have an application Config object that gathers information from several sources — .properties files, database tables, the OS, etc. — and makes this available to the rest of the application as if they were `java.util.Properties`, for example:

```
private static String devToAddress = Config.getConfig().getProperty("testAddress");
```

These are often stored, as shown above, as a static so it's always available to all instances of a class without having to constantly fetch it.

I also have a way to tell this (web) application to re-load these "properties" so I can reconfigure the application while it's running without doing a restart.

What I want to do is register with my Guava EventBus to subscribe to my "ConfigurationChangeEvent" so the class can update this `devToAddress` when I use my re-load feature.
In some cases this may be a static class with only static methods that still needs the application Config information, so I can't necessarily count on having an instance to do the work of updating the static variables.

What I tried is this:

```
package com.sample.mw;

import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;

import com.example.mw.events.ConfigurationChangeEvent;
import com.example.mw.events.EventDispatcher;
import com.example.mw.Config;

public class SampleMailer
{
    private static String devToAddress;

    // constructor(s)
    public SampleMailer()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // instance methods
    //    ...

    // static methods
    public static String getTheAddress()
    {
        return devToAddress;
    }

    @Subscribe
    public static void loadConfig(ConfigurationChangeEvent cce)
    {
        devToAddress = Config.getConfig().getProperty("testAddress");
    }

    // static/class registration with the event bus
    static
    {
        loadConfig(null); // initial config load without an event
        // 'EventDispatcher' is my singleton that encapsulates the EventBus
        EventDispatcher.getDispatcher().register(SampleMailer.class); // <-- not sure what to register here
    }
}
```

The questions are (a) Is this possible at all? Can you statically register with the Guava EventBus? (b) What *Object* do I pass to the EventBus `.register(Object object)` method?

Comment: Uhm, why don't you create a singleton instead?

Comment: The short answer is: no. A `Class` object doesn't work this way. It would be nice and symmetric though and there are languages where it would work. Not in Java though, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't register a `static` method with an `EventBus`... not directly. First of all, I'd strongly recommend trying to avoid a need for this to begin with. Static state like you have in `SampleMailer` is a smell.

That said, there's a pretty simple workaround here using an anonymous inner class:

```
eventBus.register(new Object() {
  @Subscribe
  public void loadConfig(ConfigurationChangeEvent cce) {
    SampleMailer.loadConfig(cce);
  }
});
```

But again, it should really probably be an instance method on something to begin with.

**Edit:** Huh, looks like `EventBus` *will* register a static method given an instance of that class. Still, I wouldn't recommend taking advantage of that: `EventBus` is based around registration of object *instances* as subscribers, and static subscriber methods interact somewhat strangely with that.

Comment: In Real Life, something like the example `devToAddress` isn't state and would not have a getter like that -- it is essentially a cached configuration item used strictly internally to the "SampleMailer"; thanks for the quick and concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following ColinD's answer, I found that the Guava `@Subscribe` annotation is perfectly happy registering and calling a static method, but it needs an *instance* passed for registration.
The trick is you don't want to register the subscribed static method many times, for each instance, you only want to register once so the class `loadConfig()` method (below) doesn't get called 100 times when a reload occurs.

This slightly rewritten example better demonstrates how I actually use my configuration items; there are no getters and the world outside of this Class never sees the "state" of the config vars.

```
package com.sample.mw;

import com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe;

import com.example.mw.events.ConfigurationChangeEvent;
import com.example.mw.events.EventDispatcher;
import com.example.mw.mail.Mailer;
import com.example.mw.Config;

public class SampleMailer
{
    private static boolean registered = false;

    private static String devToAddress;
    private static boolean override;

    // constructor(s)
    public SampleMailer()
    {
        if (!registered) // could be protected with synchronized() block
        {
            // 'EventDispatcher' is my singleton that encapsulates the EventBus
            // if you register 'this' instance it will find the annotated static method.
            EventDispatcher.getDispatcher().register(this);
            registered = true;
        }
    }

    // instance methods
    public void performAction(String toAddress)
    {
        doSomething( override ? devToAddress : toAddress );
    }

    private void doSomething(String toAddress)
    {
        Mailer.sendAnEmailToTheAddress(toAddress, getEmailText());
    }

    @Subscribe
    public static void loadConfig(ConfigurationChangeEvent cce)
    {
        Config config = Config.getConfig();
        devToAddress = config.getProperty("testAddress");
        override = Boolean.parseBoolean( config.getProperty("overrideMailDestination") );
    }

    // static/class initial load
    static
    {
        loadConfig(null); // initial config load without an event
    }
}
```

This is closer to the real-world use; while still only example code, it does demonstrate how static handling of guava EventBus calls can be done.